# ¿Como le puedo hacer para que el footer se quede en el pie de pagina?

Tags: html5, css3

buen dia, quiero saber como poner el footer hasta abajo del main, es decir que cuando la pagina es muy grande que el footer no aparesca hasta que se recorra con la barra, ya lo intente con todo lo que he buscado pero nada, este es el css que le puse:

css:

```
.footer{
    background-image: url("../img/swirlStripes.jpg");
    color: white;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

html:

```
<?php $refa = base_url('assets'); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?= $refa ?>/css/header.css" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="header">
        <div class="logo">
            <img src="<?= $refa ?>/img/HeaderV3_T1_Carta.png">
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr class="hr">
    <div class="main">
        <div>
            <div class="footer">
                <h5>Página creada por Macx®. Todos los derechos reservados.</h5>
            </div>
</body>

</html>
```

y me aparece asi:
[image: solo puse la parte de abajo de la pagina donde tengo el error]

como se puede ver el footer me lo muestra por encima del continido que pongo.

Comment: Puedes mostrar tu estructura html ?

Comment: ya esta listo...

Comment: `<div class="main"><div>` No estás cerrando el div main, y estás abriendo otro, entonces el Div del footer sigue dentro de main. Intenta cerrando el div de main. No estoy seguro pero dependiendo del navegador puede que se interprete de una u otra manera

Comment: pues no funciono, ya habia checado ese error y lo corregi pero nada, no funciona

Comment: No tienes otros estilos interfiriendo? Cuando corro el snippet en jsfiddle funciona http://jsfiddle.net/tqux0yk6/3/

Comment: si tengo otros estilos pero, nunca me habia pasado eso, de hecho tengo varios estilos porque estoy usando codeigniter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing `position: absolute;` in any case here is a footer example:

```
<footer class="text-center text-white">
    <p class="my-1">
      <h5>Página creada por Macx®. Todos los derechos reservados.</h5>
    </p>
</footer>
```

CSS:

```
footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 60px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

There you have your footer bottom fixed.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I had already made that option, but it did not work either, if the option of position was set to absolute, the footer remained fixed, but at the time of lowering the bar the footer moved with the bar, that is, moved towards above

Comment: Mira este link, funciona perfectamente https://jsfiddle.net/tqux0yk6/13/ utilizalo como ejemplo, que funciona y corrige tus errores en el código.

Comment: why are you speaking in english? estamos en el sitio en español

Comment: Lo sé jaja, se me ha ido la cabeza totalmente :).  Con los dos sitios de StackOverflow me he liado por completo.

Comment: ¿y por qué no la has traducido?

Answer (score 0):

```css
html {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
}
body {
    margin-bottom: 72px; /* IMPORTANTE: El margen 72px tiene que ser igual a la propiedad height que tiene el .footer */
}
.text-center{
     text-align: center;
}
.footer {
     position: absolute;
     bottom: 0;
     width: 100%;
     height: 72px; /* Establezca la altura fija del pie de página aquí */
      line-height: 60px; /* Centra verticalmente el texto */
      background-color: rgb(151, 151, 151);
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">
  <head>
    <!-- La etiqueta "meta charset=utf8"  sirve para especificar el formato de las palabras -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <!-- La etiqueta "meta name=viewport con su content" sirve para hacer responsiva la página -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">  
  </head>

<body>     
        <h4> Contenido </h4> 
    
 
 <footer class="footer">
         <div class="text-center">
              <h5> MI FOOTER </h5>
         </div>
 </footer> 
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: gracias, pero ya lo habia resuelto, le tuve que poner:

bottom: -300px;

para que se quedara abajo